# What are the special features of the recently announced Circle K Power Cube

Tags: ingress

Niantic has just announced a new type of power cube called Circle K Power Cube to be released soon. What are the special features of Circle K Power Cube?

Comment: If it isn't playable, we don't allow questions about it.  Even if the developer has talked about it.

Comment: it is available now.

Comment: I propose reopening this question. The reasons for closing no longer apply.

Comment: This should have stayed closed as per [Should we reopen questions being closed for 'unreleased game' after the game is released?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6971/4797)

Comment: @Yuu compare the post dates

Comment: @Montag451 https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240430/old-questions-marked-as-duplicate-of-newer-ones

Answer (score 2):

Niantic has also shared the special feature of the Circle K Power Cube along with its announcement.

> [This item provides greater XM storage than normal Power Cubes. Once
>   activated, the Circle K Power Cube will automatically route additional
>   XM into your Scanner as needed until it is depleted.](https://plus.google.com/+Ingress/posts/eXx3Dtmx7PA)

Comment: … except that's what the Lawson cube already does. So what's different?

Comment: This one also passively generates Circle K brand recognition 

Comment: Personal experience and consensus of other players is that it is indeed exactly the same as the Lawson Power Cube.