# What is the difference between the Circle-K and Lawson Power Cube?

Tags: ingress

Both of these Power Cubes have the same description:

> Enhanced Power Cube that provides large XM storage and automatically
>   recharges Scanner until exhausted.

**My Questions:**

1. Is there any difference between these two power cubes?
2. How much Power is initially provided?
3. Is the "automatically recharged" XM limited by time or by XM amount?

Comment: [Related](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/309088/what-are-the-special-features-of-the-recently-announced-circle-k-power-cube). I would flag this as a duplicate, but the answer has conflicting information in the comments and is unclear what the true answer is

Comment: @Wondercricket I agree that it's a very similar question and for some reason i did not see [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/309088/what-are-the-special-features-of-the-recently-announced-circle-k-power-cube) when I asked the question. But here I'm asking 3 very specific questions, which could easily be answered by an experienced player.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried it now for this post.

There is no difference. Just the name. Some companies sponsor NIA for some Ad.

AXA, Lawson, Soft Bank, etc...

The effect of this power cube is exactly the same as Lawson PC.

Keep it for anomalies (in MUFG), when you need to recharge  target / volatile  portals.

**EDIT**

Here is a link, where you can figure out how much XM will you get. It is based on your level.

https://fevgames.net/ingress/ingress-guide/items/power-cube/

Comment: Do you know how much XM is initially provided and or how long the PC is active?

Comment: @Hulkerman Yes, I've updated the post. Please accept it if it helps you.

Comment: well thanks, but it seems you forgot to embed the link hehe ;)

Comment: @Hulkerman Fixed :))

Comment: It's generally good practice to copy the relevant info to your answer, in case the link changes or no longer exists. (I've had that happen to a few of my answers in the past.)

Comment: @Ryan I'm not sure, but I think, while Ingress will exists, fev games too :))

Comment: My point is that if the URL changes for any reason, such as a site or page move, or if the site is otherwise unreachable, the link here won't be broken. From https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer: "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."